# WiX: Custom installation folder

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am new user of WiX. In installer which I am trying to develop, I need install files to some existing subfolders of C:\Users\Public\Documents. So my questions are:
1. How to check in wix if directory C:\Users\Public\Documents\myFolder exists?
2. How to write tell Wix to install files to this location.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WIX_DIR_COMMON_DOCUMENTS ([OSInfo custom actions](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/osinfo.htm)) to ship the files into Public Documents folder. Inside the **TARGETDIR** use the below code to ship the files.

```
<Directory Id="WIX_DIR_COMMON_DOCUMENTS">
    <Directory Id="SampleFolder" Name="myFolder">
        <Component Id="CMP_myFolder" Guid="{YOUR_GUID_HERE}">
          <File Id="File_Test" Source="Test.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
     </Directory>
</Directory>
```

You can use [DirectorySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_directorysearch.htm) element to check the Directory is exists or not. But you can’t use the WIX_DIR_COMMON_DOCUMENTS along with DirectorySearch element, since DirectorySearch is running in [AppSearch action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and OSInfo custom actions are run after AppSearch. So you need to write a Custom action to read the Public Documents folder.